# How to create new fragment based on Firebase Topic Message?

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a Firebase messaging service, which has a method:

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
```

that is called when a message is sent to a particular topic. I want to create a fragment in an activity based on this message. How do I pass this information to the activity?

I can't create a static method in the activity since the `getSupportFragmentManager()` method is non-static and must be called in order to create a fragment.

Comment: Is there some interface with this method? If so, you should have a callback mechanism to get that message to the Activity

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in different ways.

One example is using a `LocalBroadcastManager` to send a "within the app" intent from the FirebaseMessagingService to a receiver registered dynamically inside the onCreate() method of your activity.

https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/report-status.html